# Title SilverAppBar without margins

Tags: flutter

Is posible remove all margins in title in silverApp bar?

```
SliverAppBar(
    floating: true,
    snap: true,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    elevation: 0,
    title: Container(
       width: double.infinity,
       color: Colors.green,
       child: Text('title')))
```

Here is an image shows what I need
[image]

Comment: hello @Mus Are you there/

Comment: What you Exactly want

Answer (score 0):

check here, hope this will work for you.

```
Scaffold(
  body: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,

            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text(
                "SliverAppBar",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
              /*background: Image.network(
                "image url goes here",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),*/
            ),
          )
        ];
      },
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hello World"),
      )),
)
```